# Holes in model after applying subdivide modifier

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface, 3d-printing, solidify-modifier

I'm trying to make a model 3D print ready and after applying a subdivision modifier, there are several holes in the model. I've seen some people say to recalculate the normals or use solidifier but neither worked for me. Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This looks like the result of applying a subdivision surface modifier to edges/verts that are not properly connected. Try selecting the whole mesh in edit mode, then press M (merge) and select by distance".

Answer (score 0):

This is how the subdivision modifier works. If you want to prevent this you can :

- Add more geometry (i.e. loop cuts or insets) near the edges
- Use a crease
- Switch the interpolation mode from Catmull-Clark to Simple in the subdiv settings
- Remove the modifier (are you sure you need 5 levels by the way?)

The choice is up to you.

I am not too sure what your model is, but it looks like a torso. Why don't you simply connect the vertices to fill the holes?